# Why do we need to specify logger only on Controller level

Tags: spring, kotlin

I noticed that it's enough to specify a logger on controller level.

```
import ...

val logger = KotlinLogging.logger { }

@RestController
```

A subsequent service is able to access this logger without specifying a logger for itself.

In other words - if a service complains about not being able to call `logger.info {"..."}` then it is enough to add `val logger = KotlinLogging.logger { }` to a calling controller of that service.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to update this as `the preferred way` stated by Jaoa is not what the developers say themselves:

https://github.com/MicroUtils/kotlin-logging/wiki#obtaining-a-logger

```
The preferred way to obtain a logger is as follows:

// Place definition above class declaration, below imports, 
// to make field static and accessible only within the file

private val logger = KotlinLogging.logger {}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I still prefer the companion object alternative. Why? If you have multiple classes in a single file you would be able to use the same logger for all of them, which is somewhat weird to me.

Comment: I totally agree. This is what lead me to the original question. But I guess it's the way to go

Answer (score 2):

When you create variables like that you are basically creating a top-level variable that might be accessible from anywhere in your code. That is why if you add it to the Controller, the Service will be able to use it.

However, this does not mean you should do that. The recommended way to create a KotlinLogger is using companion objects as follows:

```kotlin
import ...

@RestController
class WhateverController {
    companion object {
        private val logger = KotlinLogging.logger {}
    }
}
```

This means that you will have a logger for each class, as you should.

Comment: Thank you. The logger is only available downstream, meaning I cannot access it from a service that's not being called by the controller. So every controller needs to state their own logger. Can you give more insight into what seems to be procedural flow being applied here? I'd get if it's just a 'global variable' that can be accessed from anywhere, but that's not true.

Comment: It should be accessible from anywhere. You just need to import it. This is not necessary if your Service and Controller are in the same package.

Comment: Ahh, that's it. Thank you so much for your answers!

Comment: Please see my updated comment, it is not the preferred way to include the logger in a companion object!